# Possible event bug in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I think I've been suffering from a very strange bug. There might be something systematically broken with `EventEmitter`. Ever since I started using the `once` function things seem off.

The following lines of console output demonstrate what's happening:

```
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
a = new EventEmitter();
a.on("bla", function() { console.log("perm");});
a.once("bla", function() { console.log("this is temp"); });
a.emit('bla');
```

You would expect both events to be called, but on my console the output is:

```
> a.emit("bla")
perm
perm
true
```

What's going on??

I've also tried using the code in a script and that seemed to work but I'm getting the feeling that the `once` function is somehow responsible for the weird glitches on my server.

Anyone ever encountered this?

[Tested on versions 0.5.1 and 0.5.3]

Comment: First rule of programming ... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/03/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault.html

Comment: I tested it with the newest windows version (5.5). Output was perm\nthis is temp ;) Have you tested the code above?

Comment: First, the v0.5.x branch is an "unstable branch", so you should probably stick to v0.4.x if you find bugs. Second, I've run this same code with v0.4.9, and it works just fine, even with several consecutive emits.

Comment: tested on 0.4.10, same result as FlashFan, so, looking good

Comment: It does work for me with a .js file, but not in the console.

Comment: Calling the `once` function frequently on the server will result in the `EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added...` message. Seems as if `once` is broken or just not removing the listeners

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me on 0.5.10. I'm pretty sure you typed something else than what you posted here - where could the second "perm" come from? Try it again.

```
$ node
> var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
> a = new EventEmitter();
{}
> a.on("bla", function() { console.log("perm");});
{ _events: { bla: [Function] } }
> a.once("bla", function() { console.log("this is temp"); });
{ _events: { bla: [ [Function], [Object] ] } }
> a.emit('bla');
perm
this is temp
true
>
```

Comment: Yeah, I didn't encounter it after the 0.5.4 build. Probably just something weird with the REPL.